# What key considerations should be kept in mind when creating a VASP POSCAR file?

Tags: vasp

What factors can cause convergence issues in VASP calculations and how can they be avoided when creating the POSCAR file? Additionally, could you provide information about the recommended number of processor groups for a VASP job?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more understandable. However, I am still not so clear about your request here. The POSCAR file just holds your cell and ions positions. POSCAR file just needs to be reasonable in a way that atoms are for instance not overlapping unless you might get into an endless loop in convergence. I believe your question is about the tags that should be considered in the INCAR file in the case of facing convergence issues? let me know if that is your request? then update your question and I will try to give you an answer.